# my countdown clock beings counting down one turn after it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, countdown, countdowntimer

I have a working countdown clock except for the fact that it begins counting down one 'turn' after it should. I have a button which starts the game and starts the clock. I press it and it retrieves and shows my random number (say 5) and displays my random number of inputs (5). But the countdown says 0. which is `(20 * null)` of the loading page (`this.state` loads as `null`). I press start again, and there is a new random number but the countdown begins counting down from (5 * 20) instead of the new random number. I am a bit at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The whole code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

let timer = null

class StartButton extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.name}</button>
      )
    }
  }

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.state = {
        ranNum: null,
        restart: false,
        timer: null
      };
  }

  handleClick() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    this.clearForm();
    this.generateRanNum();
    this.generateInputs();
    // this.changeToRestartText()
    this.countdownClock();
  }

   generateRanNum = () => {
      let ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
       this.setState({
          ranNum: ranNum,
        })

    }

  clearForm = () => {
  if(this.state.restart === true){
      const inputLi = <Input />;
      inputLi.map(element => {
          element.remove()
      });
     const subButton = <SubmitButton />
      subButton.remove()
  }
}

countdownClock = async () => {
const startingNum = this.state.ranNum * 20;
for(let i = startingNum; i >= 0; i--) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
         this.setState({
           timer: i
         })
        resolve()
     }, 1000)
   });
  }
}

generateInputs = () => {
    const inputs = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= this.state.ranNum; i++){
      inputs.push(
        <Input type='text' className='textInputs' />
      )
    }
    return inputs;
  }

  generateSubButton = () => {
    return (
      <SubmitButton name='Submit Button' />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <div className="headerContainer">
              <div id="countdown">
                <Countdown name='Countdown: ' countdown={this.state.timer} />
              </div>
              <div className="flex-item-header">
                <StartButton 
                    name={!this.state.restart ? 'Start Button' : 'Restart Button'}
                    onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
                />            
                </div>
              <div>
                  <DisplayCount name='Word Count: ' count={this.state.ranNum} />
              </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <section>
          <div className="flex-main-item"> 
            <ul>
              {this.generateInputs()}
            </ul>
            {this.generateSubButton()}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class SubmitButton extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
      <button name={this.props.name} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
      </button>
    )
  }
}

class DisplayCount extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.props.name}
        <span>{this.props.count}</span>
      </p>
    )
  }
}

class Countdown extends React.Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
      <p>
        {this.props.name}
        <span>{this.props.countdown}</span>
      </p>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your code for `generateRanNum` but unless it's setting the state, then the first time you run `this.countdownClock()`, `state.ranNum` is still `null` from the initalization of the component. You need to set that state first before you start counting down.

Comment: Just posted the ```generateRanNum``` function. I am still kind of a newbie but I think I set the ranNum correctly, unless I cant use a variable like that with a ```this.state``` object

Comment: Having access to the whole code would be helpful to see where methods live and such, but I suspect removing the return statement from your `generateRanNum` function will fix the problem. You don't need to return anything, just update the state. I'm suspicious that `this` isn't referring to the thing you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Moral of story: Setting component state in React is async.

You set `ranNum` state in `generateRanNum()` then you read `this.state.ranNum` in `countdownClock()`, expecting it to be up-to-date. Well, it’s not because `setState()` is async.

I guess you’re aware of the concept of component lifecycle. Any call to `setState()` will cause a round of call to lifecycle hook methods. But these calls are buffered and batch applied for performance reason, thus async.

`this.state` is not updated until `componentWillUpdate()` of "next round" is called. Yet you access it prematurely in "this round". Thus the countdown lags behind one turn, cus it indeed reads the old value.

Quick fix to your code:

```
const ranNum = this.generateRanNun();
this.countdownClock(ranNum);
```

Cheers.

Comment: That completely fixed the problem. Thank you so much. Out of curiosity, some of my functions worked just fine using ```this.state.ranNum``` why is that variable available for some things and not others basically in the same 'round'?

Comment: If you mean `generateInputs()`, it works because it’s called inside `render()` method, that’s not the same round.

Comment: "Round" is vague, think about the event loop model, it’s much clear. If you’re not familiar with the concept, I highly recommend  reading about it.

Comment: I will definitely read about it! I have super vague knowledge about it at the moment.